# encoding email address using c# and decoding using javascript in a gridview

Tags: c#, javascript, gridview

I am a new user to .net so forgive me if my problem is too basic.

I have a gridview displaying users information including emails. Now I want to encode these emails from server side and decode them from client side.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function UncryptedMailTo(s) {
        var n = 0;
        var r = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
            n = s.charCodeAt(i);
            if (n >= 8364) { n = 128; }
            r += String.fromCharCode(n - (1));
        }
        return r;
    }
    function ShowEmail(s) {
        location.href = UncryptedMailTo(s);
    }

</script>


<asp:GridView ID="GridView_Users" runat="server"  OnRowDataBound="GridView_Users_RowDataBound" >
    <Columns>            
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="Email">
            <ItemTemplate>
               <a href="javascript:ShowEmails(<%# Eval("Email", "mailto:{0}") %>)">write email</a>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I want to write the encoding code with c# but I don't know how to get the value of `<%# Eval("Email", "mailto:{0}") %>` and pass it back. Can anyone give me a hint how to do that?

Comment: I think you're confusing 'encoded' with 'encrypted', based on the JavaScript you've shown.

Comment: thanks! You are right, I mean 'encoded', just some simple trick to hide the actual email from spams.